# JOLT transformation add the same elements into all arrays

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I want to add the same values to every element of an array.
My approach is to use default to add the value.
It is a litte bit different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877383/jolt-transformation-add-element-to-array), because:
I don't know how to write into an existing element of the array instead of a new one.

Input:

```json
{
  "counterTop": {
    "loaf1": [
      {
        "type": "white",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "correct"
      },
      {
        "type": "black",
        "unit": "cm",
        "test": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Specs:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "counterTop": {
        "loaf1": {
          "*": {
            "slices": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "counterTop": {
    "loaf1": [
      {
        "type": "white",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "correct",
        "slices": ""
      },
      {
        "type": "black",
        "unit": "cm",
        "test": "false",
        "slices": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Current output

```json
{
  "counterTop": {
    "loaf1": [
      {
        "type": "white",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "correct"
      },
      {
        "type": "black",
        "unit": "cm",
        "test": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone here have a solution? Outside the array it works without problems, but I can't get in there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JOLT transformation add element to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877383/jolt-transformation-add-element-to-array)

Comment: Not really, have already seen this question and also tried to modify the specs a bit, but don't really get anywhere. I don't know how to write into an existing element of the array instead of a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be applying shift transformation twice; in order to extract key-value pairs of the list(`loaf1`) by going innermost level while adding new key-value pair(`"slices":" "`) within the first step, and then combining all lists back to the original within the second one such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&",
            "# ": "slices"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "counterTop.loaf1[&].&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works pretty good for me, but if I want to add more attributes to the array, how can I do that? Or do I need to repeat all for every attribute?

Comment: you're welcome @kingsven149 . You'll see that new elements are appended to the each object memebers of the array whenever you add `"#abc": "slices2","#def": "slices3"` next to `"# ": "slices"` as an example.

Comment: Oh yes, thats right, thanks. But the problem is, that I need to file the attributes with values, but I want attributes without any values. 
I got `"#abc": "slices2","#def": "slices3"`  but I want  `"#": "slices2","#": "slices3"`. 
But I guess, that this is not possible only with more spaces `"#  ": "slices2","#   ": "slices3"`.